# The proper way to compute correlation between two Seq columns into a third column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, correlation

I have a DataFrame where each row has 3 columns:

```
ID:Long, ratings1:Seq[Double], ratings2:Seq[Double]
```

For each row I need to compute the correlation between those Vectors.

I came up with the following solution which seems to be inefficient (not working as Jarrod Roberson has mentioned) as I have to create RDDs for each Seq:

```
val similarities = ratingPairs.map(row => {
      val ratings1 = sc.parallelize(row.getAs[Seq[Double]]("ratings1"))
      val ratings2 = sc.parallelize(row.getAs[Seq[Double]]("ratings2"))
      val corr:Double = Statistics.corr(ratings1, ratings2)

      Similarity(row.getAs[Long]("ID"), corr)
    })
```

Is there a way to compute such correlations properly?

Comment: what is `ratingPairs`? if it's an `RDD` or a `DataFrame` - your solution isn't inefficient, it simply won't work - you *can't* create an RDD within a transformation on another RDD's/DataFrame

Comment: Ah.. alright. Now I see why the job could never finish (although no runtime errors were shown). ratingPairs is a DataFrame, yes. So, now is there any way to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have a correlation function for arrays:

```
def correlation(arr1: Array[Double], arr2: Array[Double]): Double
```

(for potential implementations of that function, which is completely independent of Spark, you can ask a separate question or search online, there are some close-enough resource, e.g. [this implementation](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-pearson-correlation-score-algorithm-programming-collective-intelligence)).

Now, all that's left to do is to wrap this function with a **UDF** and use it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val corrUdf = udf {
  (arr1: Seq[Double], arr2: Seq[Double]) => correlation(arr1.toArray, arr2.toArray)
}

val result = df.select($"ID", corrUdf($"ratings1", $"ratings2") as "correlation")
```